# нужно вывести многомерное меню с массива

Tags: php

есть некий массив

```
$arr = [
'Home' => '1.php',
'колокольня' => [
        'КОЛОКОЛЬНЯ1' => [
               'Страстной КОЛОКОЛЬНЯ 1800 реконструкция' => '01.php', 
               'Страстной КОЛОКОЛЬНЯ 1830 реконструкция' => '10.php',
               'Страстной КОЛОКОЛЬНЯ 1930 реконструкция' => '1000.php',
               'Страстной КОЛОКОЛЬНЯ 10 реконструкция' => '10.php',
               'Страстной КОЛОКОЛЬНЯ 18370 реконструкция' => '10.php',
               'Страстной КОЛОКОЛЬНЯ 193077 реконструкция' => '1000.php'
                           ]],
'Foto' => '1.php',                             
'Contact' => '130.php',
'Contact2' => '130.php',
```

];

вывожу так

```
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) {

    if (!is_array($value)){

    echo '<li class="has-sub"><a href="'.$value.'"><span>'.$key.'</span></a> 
    </li>'."\n";
    }
    if (is_array($value)){

    echo '<li class="has-sub"><a href="'.$value.'"><span>'.$key.'</span></a>'."\n<ul>\n";

    foreach ( $value as $key1 => $value1 ) {


    echo '<li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>'.$key1.'</span></a>'."\n<ul>\n";

    if (is_array($value1)){

    foreach ( $value1 as $key10 => $value10 ) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$value10.'"><span>'.$key10.'</span></a></li>'."\n";

    }

   echo  "\n</ul></li></ul>\n";


    }

    }
    }
     }
```

вывод работает правильно.
но если я добавляю новые элементы в массив (подменю).
меню выводиться не верно (

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Рекурсия

Answer (score 0):

Пример вам вот, скопировано из своего куска кода.

```
  function DrawMenu($id,$menu)
  {
    $result = '';
    if(isset($menu[$id]))
    {
      $result .= "<ul>";
      foreach($menu[$id] as $val)
      {
        $result .= "<li><a href='./page/".$val['id']."' >".$val['description']."</a>";
          $result .= DrawMenu($val['id'],$menu);
        $result .= "</li>";
      }
      $result .= "</ul>";
    } 
    return $result;
  }
```

Надеюсь сможете переписать под себя..

Comment: спасибо. но это для меня сложновато.

Comment: Не надо вставлять в ответ код в виде картинки. Вставьте текстовый код в ответ, чтобы он был доступен для поиска и копирования

Comment: Вставил картинкой сначало чтоб автор вопроса не тупо скопировал код, а попытался его понять пока переписывал =) теперь понимаю тщетность потуг =) оставил голым кодом =) в любом случае его придется понять перед тем как получится использовать